# Overloading_grade_program_accelerated_c++_book

Tags: c++, overloading

So I am doing exercises in an "Accelerated C++" book. But, when I try to rework the code from the book, Visual Studio keeps saying more than one instance of overloaded function, `grade`, matches the argument list. But I can not see where is the overloading problem. Can someone please help me with this ?

## grade.h

```
#ifndef GUARD_grade_h
#define GUARD_grade_h

#include <vector>
#include "student_info.h"

double grade(double, double, double);
double grade(double, double, const std::vector<double>&);
double grade(const Student_info &);

#endif // !GUARD_grade_h
```

## grade.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "median.h"
#include "student_info.h"
#include "grade.h"

using std::domain_error; using std::vector;

double grade(double midterm, double final, double homeworks) 
{
    return 0.2 * midterm + 0.4 * final + 0.4 * homeworks;
}

double grade(double midterm, double final, const vector<double> hm)
{
    if (hm.size() == 0)
        throw domain_error("student has done no homework");
    return grade(midterm, final, median(hm));
}

double grade(const Student_info& s)
{
    return grade(s.midterm, s.final, s.homework); // this grade is saying that is more then one
    //instance of overloaded function "grade"
}
```

Comment: Please include the exact error message in your question, it should continue to list the candidate functions and the types it tried to match with.

Comment: be careful with `final` as it's a keyword, choose another name for that parameter

Comment: Read the prototypes for the vector variant carefully. (Prototypes is one of the few cases where copy-and-paste is a great way to create code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration and definition of your second overload for `grade()` (the one with the vector as the third argument) don't match. The declaration has the vector passed *by reference*, but your definition has it passed *by value*. You missed out an `&` in the latter.

As it stands, when the compiler sees the `grade(s.midterm, s.final, s.homework);` call (in the definition of the last overload), it doesn't know which of the two 'possible' overloads to use: pass `s.homework` by reference or by value?